# set notification on alarm receiver android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to set an alaram programmatically.
Setting alarm is working properly but how can i apply notification to this on recieving alarm.

I have gone through notifications in developer guide.

Please find the code.

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent alaram=new Intent(Alarmmanager.this,GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarmmanager.this, 0, alaram,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent); 
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

    sendBroadcast(alaram,"setalaram");
```

and in broadcast receiver

```
public class GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{ 

@Override 
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) { 
 Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

 }
```

It is working fine but to set notification i need to set notification manager which works fine only in activity extended class ,how can i use it on receive and notify.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use your `context` in `onReceive` to find the `NotificationManager` and call `notify`:

```
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notifications = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifications.notify( ... );
}
```

If you have a `Context` you can do just about anything! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply let me try and check

Comment: Why not? You can't do context.getSystemService( ... )?

Comment: most of the things you can do with `Activity` you can also do with `Context`.

Comment: can u tell me any manifest entry for it and tell me how to start notification intent I am new for it

Comment: @MatthewWillis: hello, I have Done as you have said but there are one issue with the notification. Please see this and help me for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937333/android-alarm-notification-issue

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful to just use the BuzzBox SDK to schedule a task and to create notifications. It supports a crontab string to schedule recurring tasks. [BuzzBox SDK Website](http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/)