# how set alarm along with notification?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

i've been doing on my alarm project..

my code is like this :

```
    String a = interval.getText().toString();

   Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Integer.parseInt(a)*1000, pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            int icon = R.drawable.alarm_icon;
            CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
            CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, AndroidAlarmService.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AndroidAlarmService.this.getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

            final int HELLO_ID = 1;

            mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

   Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }});
```

i've got a problem, the notification always came out once, it's not come out repeatly.

i want to set a repeatable alarm along with notification, so everytime the alarm active, the notification will come out too... for the example, when i set an alarm every 1 hours, so every one hours, the alarm will trigger and the notification will also come out..

anyone can help me? thanks before

Comment: why you put the notification in the same class where you set the alarm. Notification should be in MyAlarmService class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307664/set-notification-on-alarm-receiver-android

Answer (score 0):

pass your Notification in Service class i.e inside the onStartCommand()