# Android : Alarm Notification Issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-manifest, android-notifications

In My application i have set the many Alarm Notification.
All are at different date but with the same time. And i am setting it on/off with the help of the toggle Button.

Now the Problem is, If i am setting it on then at that time it gives me notification of the previous one from current date. it only appear at once and then all alarm notification works fine.

Suppose if i have set the alarm at 12,14,16 date then i set the date as 15 in my device and on the toggle button then it gives me notification of 14 at that time. And then all goes fine.

So is it logically correct or is there any problem in my code ?

Should it be happened or not ?

Please see the Below code that i have set for the alarm notification:

```
public void startTwoMonthAlarmNotification() {

        // ===================== GST ALARM FOR THE TWO MONTHS ==========================
        // for the GST 20 June 2011
        AM_2M_GST_1 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in1.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 20th June 2011.");
        PI_2M_GST_1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, in1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_18_June_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_18_June_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_18_June_2011.set(2011, 5, 18, mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calendar_GST_18_June_2011.getTimeInMillis(), PI_2M_GST_1);

        // for the GST 19 August 2011
        AM_2M_GST_2 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in2 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in2.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 19th August 2011.");
        PI_2M_GST_2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, in2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_17_August_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_17_August_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_17_August_2011.set(2011, 7, 17,mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_August_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_2);

        // for the GST 21 October 2011  
        AM_2M_GST_3 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in3 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in3.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 21st October 2011.");
        PI_2M_GST_3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, in3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_19_October_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_19_October_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_19_October_2011.set(2011, 9, 19,mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_19_October_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_3);

        // for the GST 17 December 2011 
        AM_2M_GST_4 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in4 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in4.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 19th December 2011.");
        PI_2M_GST_4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, in4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_17_December_2011 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_17_December_2011.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_17_December_2011.set(2011, 11, 17,mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_4.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_17_December_2011.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_4);
        /////////////////////////////////////
        // for the GST 26 February 2012 
        AM_2M_GST_5 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in5 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in5.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 28th February 2012.");
        PI_2M_GST_5 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, in5, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_26_February_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_26_February_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_26_February_2012.set(2012, 1, 26,mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_5.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_26_February_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_5);
        /////////////////////
    // for the GST 27 April 2012    
        AM_2M_GST_6 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in6 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in6.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 29th April 2012.");
        PI_2M_GST_6 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 5, in6, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_27_April_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_27_April_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_27_April_2012.set(2012, 3, 27,mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_6.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_27_April_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_6);

    // for the GST 16 January 2012  
        AM_2M_GST_7 = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent in7 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth.class);
        in7.putExtra("MyMessage","Your 2 Monthly GST return is DUE on 16th January 2012.");
        PI_2M_GST_7 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 6, in7, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar_GST_16_January_2012 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_GST_16_January_2012.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar_GST_16_January_2012.set(2012, 0, 14,mHour, mMinute, 0);
        AM_2M_GST_7.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar_GST_16_January_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_2M_GST_7);
        }
```

Below code is for the Canceling all the notification alarm on the toogleButton off:

```
        AM_2M_GST_1.cancel(PI_2M_GST_1);
    AM_2M_GST_2.cancel(PI_2M_GST_2);
    AM_2M_GST_3.cancel(PI_2M_GST_3);
    AM_2M_GST_4.cancel(PI_2M_GST_4);
    AM_2M_GST_5.cancel(PI_2M_GST_5);
    AM_2M_GST_6.cancel(PI_2M_GST_6);
    AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_1.cancel(PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_1);
    AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_2.cancel(PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_2);
    AM_2M_PROVISIONAL_3.cancel(PI_2M_PROVISIONAL_3);
    AM_2M_TERMINAL_1.cancel(PI_2M_TERMINAL_1);
```

Comment: maybe it's an indexing problem.  You should post some code n stuff.

Comment: @dokkaebi : please see the updated question. That i am using to set the alarm. Whats wrong with that ? And Is My logic set to it or not ?

Comment: @dokkaebi: Do you have any idea how to solve it or why it is like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must cancel the old AlarmManager and Pending Intent. Here you didn't cancel your Pending Intent. Just cancel that use thic code -

```
alaramManagerObj.cancel(pendingIntent);
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

This will be clear your unWanted Notification and works only for provided Alarm. If you want to Check your alarm with Specified date for that date is passed or not. Just check with this -

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.set(2011, 1, 20); 
long mills = c.getTimeInMillis(); 
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
int x = (mills<=currentTime)?0:1;
```

In the integer `x` will return 0 if the date is not passed, else returns 1. Use this code to your needs.

Hope this may helps you.